Why is this not in the dative case?
"Er kommt jede Woche zu uns."
Why is "jede Woche" in the accusative case here and not the dative case as "jeder Woche"?

Why should it be dative? I mean, do you know any rule that says so?

Related question

This is a so-called adverbialer Akkusativ. It describes a certain time span or a distance and cannot be replaced by a pronoun:

Wir gehen jeden Monat ins Kino. (timespan)
Ich arbeite den ganzen Tag.
Wir haben ihn den halben Weg getragen. (distance)

Notice that it is not required by the Verb and can therefore stand with Verben that do not use a Akkusativobjekt. It remains an Akkusativ if a sentence is translated into Passiv:

Es wird jeden Monat von uns ins Kino gegangen.
Den ganzen Tag wurde von mir gearbeitet.
Er wurde den halben Weg von uns getragen.


The rule is that time expressions without a preposition, such as "jede Woche", take the accusative case, and time expression with a preposition, such as "vor einer Woche", take the dative. Perhaps you've only seen such expressions with prepositions up til now.

Thanks for the explanation! Just to be sure I understand correctly, when you write that "time expression with a preposition, such as "vor einer Woche", take the dative", how about the following: "Ich fahre für eine Woche nach England"? Shall I propose the following rule: "time expresssion with a preposition take the Dative, with the exceptions of 'auf', 'für' and 'über' (Akkusativ), as well as 'binnen' and 'während' (Genitiv)"?

@Sylvain Gadenne - Right. Since für always takes accusative it wouldn't make sense to use dative with it. And genitive prepositions would similarly imply genitive. But auf and über are variable. In the case of über I think the idea is that the time period is something you pass though, so it takes accusative. I couldn't find many examples with auf, but I'll take your word for it. I stated the rule I as I learned it, but it's German so there have to be exceptions.

The difference is: "vor einer Woche" is a point in time whereas "für eine Woche" or "die ganze Woche über" mean a timespan. The point in time is described by the Dativ, the timespan requires the Akkusativ. This is similar to the "place/direction"-dichotomy.

Thanks @RDBury and bakunin for the explanations!
